# What is the consequence of blotting Moses' name out of the book?

Tags: exodus

> Exodus 32:30The next day Moses said to the people, “You have committed a great sin. But now I will go up to the Lord; perhaps I can make atonement for your sin.”
>
> 31So Moses went back to the Lord and said, “Oh, what a great sin these people have committed! They have made themselves gods of gold. 32But now, please forgive their sin—but if not, then blot me out of the book you have written.”

Did Moses know that he would lose his eternal life?

Answer (score 1):

In Exodus / **Shemot 32:32**, we read : “And now, if You forgive their sin But if not, erase me now from Your Scroll, which You have written” ( וְעַתָּ֖ה אִם־תִּשָּׂ֣א חַטָּאתָ֑ם וְאִם־אַ֕יִן מְחֵ֣נִי נָ֔א מִסִּפְרְךָ֖ אֲשֶׁ֥ר כָּתָֽבְתָּ ). Moshe משֶׁ֑ה is demonstrating both compassion for Yisrael and more importantly יִרְאַ֣ת יְ֖הוָה Fear of YHVH.

Moshe משֶׁ֑ה does not refer simply to his name being removed from HaTorah but instead references God’s **Sefer Zikaron סֵ֣פֶר זִכָּר֚וֹן (Scroll of Remembrance)** used to acknowledge a soul’s life. Sefer Zikaron maintains a soul’s life if the soul demonstrates Fear of YHVH as described later in מַלְאָכִֽי Malaki 3:16:

“Then the God-fearing men spoke to one another, and YHVH hearkened and heard it. And a Scroll of Remembrance was written before Him for those who feared YHVH and for those who valued His Name highly.” ( אָ֧ז נִדְבְּר֛וּ יִרְאֵ֥י יְהֹוָ֖ה אִ֣ישׁ אֶל־רֵעֵ֑הוּ וַיַּקְשֵׁ֚ב יְהֹוָה֙ וַיִּשְׁמָ֔ע וַ֠יִּכָּתֵב סֵ֣פֶר זִכָּר֚וֹן לְפָנָיו֙ לְיִרְאֵ֣י יְהֹוָ֔ה וּלְחֹֽשְׁבֵ֖י שְׁמֽוֹ )

In recognition of Moshe’s reverent Fear, God acknowledges the compassionate heroism of משֶׁ֑ה Moshe stating in Exodus / **Shemot 32:33**: "Whoever has sinned against Me, him I will erase from My Scroll!" ( מִ֚י אֲשֶׁ֣ר חָֽטָא־לִ֔י אֶמְחֶ֖נּוּ מִסִּפְרִֽי )

Comment: +1, for connecting this to the scroll of remembrance

Comment: It is not a book that men have written. 'Thy book which thou hast written' [KJV].  The scroll of remembrance was written by men. Written 'before God' yes. But not by God.

Comment: @Nigel J - Ask the Group’s opinion : Is the Sefer Zikaron from Malaki 3:16 the same Sefer Chayim from Tehillim 69:29 (KJV-Psalm 69:28)?